# How to avoid same query execution multiple times?

Tags: java, hibernate

I need an approach through which I can avoid same query execution multiple times.
I dont need any help from the code perspective. A high level approach will be fine.

Currently I am executing same hibernate query in different classes and these executions are part of same request. 
As of now I am using a request level cache to store the data. Later I am fetching those data  from cache instead of DB to improve performance. But I want to know if there is any other approach which I can follow apart from above approach.

It will be very helpful if you can help on this.

Thanks

Comment: I am a bit surprised that a query that is repeated is not returned in ~0 ms by the database itself.

Comment: I would recommend refactoring of the relevant parts of the code, so that the problematic query is executed only once per request.

Comment: @Joop Eggen .. Thanks for your response. Is it an existing feature of Oracle or Hibernate ?

Comment: No, "out-of-the-box" in DBs (not entirely true) repeated queries often are almost instantly (DB2, Oracle, even  MySQL) under circumstances. One should check the times. I once "optimized" a dropdown list of DB data in a table without need. Really depressing to have produced a nice solution and then to find that out.

Comment: If you did not already, have a look at query caching in Hibernate https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch06.html#d0e2601

Answer (score 0):

You can register a web listener which will implement `ServletContextListener`.
You will need to implement `contextInitialized` (application deploy) and `contextDestroyed` (application undeploy).

```
@WebListener
public final class CacheBootstrap implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
       // load data into cache (hql?)
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
       // unload data from cache (hql?)
    }
}
```